# p5.js ellipse and rect behavior

Tags: javascript, processing, p5.js

I'm confused by the way p5 treats location say this...

If I put down:

```
ellipse(10,10,20);
rect(10, 10, 20, someNumber);
```

Then the shapes are misaligned!
WHY!?

Comment: someNumber value ?

Comment: No, that was just used as a place holder because it serves no purpose to the question

Comment: Basically, any value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The alignment of the ellipse depends on the [`ellipseMode()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/ellipseMode) and the alignment of the rectangle depends on the [`rectMode()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/rectMode). While the default rectangle mode is `CORNER`, the default ellipse mode is `CENTER`. Use the same mode for both shapes:

```js
function setup() {
    createCanvas(100, 100);
}

function draw() {
    background(255);
    noFill();
    ellipseMode(CENTER);
    rectMode(CENTER);
    ellipse(50, 50, 90);
    rect(50, 50, 90, 90);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.0.0/p5.min.js"></script>
```